# Zero intersection of two ideals in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_{4}\left[ x\right] /\left\langle x^{n}-1\right\rangle .$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $n$ be an odd integer and  $f,g,h$ be monic polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ such that  $x^{n}-1=fgh.$ Also let $\left\langle fh,2fg\right\rangle $ and $\left\langle g^{\ast }h^{\ast },2f^{\ast }g^{\ast }\right\rangle $ (where $"^{\ast }"$ represents the reciprocal of the polynomials) be two ideals of the quotient ring $R=\mathbb{Z}_{4}\left[ x\right] /\left\langle x^{n}-1\right\rangle .$ I am trying to determine under which conditions the intersection $\left\langle fh,2fg\right\rangle \cap \left\langle g^{\ast
}h^{\ast },2f^{\ast }g^{\ast }\right\rangle $ is $\left\{ 0\right\} .$ To do
this, I know that $lcm\left( fh,g^{\ast }h^{\ast }\right) |x^{n}-1$
and $lcm\left( fg,f^{\ast }g^{\ast }\right) |x^{n}-1,$ but I can't go
further. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I must be missing something: Since $f,g$, and $h$ divide $x^n-1$ they will be zero-divisors in the quotient ring. In what sense will thy have ``reciprocals"?

Comment: Dear John, because $f, g$ and $h$ are the multiplication of the basic irreducible polynomials and hence are monic polynomials.

Comment: I still don't follow this. Why do you say that monic polynomials have reciprocals? What is the reciprocal of $x+1$?

Comment: Dear John, the reciprocal definition is based on the book "Wan, Z. (1997).
Quaternary codes (Vol. 8). World Scientific." In the mentioned book, the
author describes the reciprocal of the polynomial $h\left( x\right)
=h_{0}+h_{1}x+\ldots +h_{r}x^{r}$ as $h^{\ast }\left( x\right)
=h_{r}+h_{r-1}x+\ldots +h_{1}x^{r-1}+h_{0}x^{r}.$ According to this
definition the polynomial $x+1$ is self-reciprocal.

Comment: Oh! What a very poor choice of notation! But sorry, now I can't help you with your question.